# Power BI API Power Query

Tags: api, powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-api

[this is the response from the api call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAjBM.png)Hi I'm stuck with this problem, I am querying an API that only allows you to bring back 10 records at a time. Then you have to do another call and provide the next page key to get the next batch of 10 records and so forth. Is there a way for Power BI to use a variable to pull in the next page key from the response, and then use it in the API call to cycle through the data till the end of the data.

Comment: Can you show us your REST call? Why does the API limit you to 10? The best solution is unlikely to involve looping through batches of 10 at a time, especially to populate a Power BI dataset.

Comment: the API was designed that way by the vendor. this is the response of the call
i have attached the response of the call in the hyperlink in my question above 

this is the api call that i make 

https://dynamon.server5.bina.net/e/4396-a544-c9ced0861299/api/v2/problems?fields=impactAnalysis

Comment: You need to create a loop with a function, here more details: https://medium.com/@marktiedemann/how-to-do-pagination-in-power-query-430460c17c78